# Show first chart from 3

Tags: angularjs, charts, nvd3.js

I want to have a multiple charts, but when I do it by

```
$scope.data = [
            {
                values: day, //values - represents the array of {x,y} data points
                key: 'Проходимость',//key  - the name of the series.

            },
            {
                values: day, //values - represents the array of {x,y} data points
                key: 'Проходимость' //key  - the name of the series.
            },
            {
                values: day, //values - represents the array of {x,y} data points
                key: 'Проходимость' //key  - the name of the series.
            }
        ];`
```

I see that all of 3 charts are in block visible. I want to first chart to be visible and second and third - invisible

Answer (score 0):

I found some answer on my question: you should to use "disabled"

```
{
            values: sales,
            key: 'Покупок',
            disabled: true
        },
```